# ThreeJS weird camera movement around mesh using OrbitControls

Tags: three.js

Recently I have migrated from R95 to R99 and seems like I'm having some issues dealing with the new Perspective camera updates and also with OrbitControls.

Until now, the camera was a children of a Group, which contained a mesh which was the main point of reference. (When the container was moving, the camera was also moving together with it)

After updating past R96 I noticed that this behavior is no longer working properly resulting the camera still following the mesh, but panning, rotating the camera resulted in some sort of rotation not around the mesh which is the point of reference but around an invisible point in space

I also noticed that this has something to do with the current position of the container Group since it's working fine when the Group is at (0,0,0) but not when it's position is different.

The only difference is in the examples below is: `cube.position.set(10, 10, 10);`

Here is an example:

- https://jsfiddle.net/qb18ozm0/2/ - Expected behavior (cube position set
  at (0,0,0))
  https://jsfiddle.net/qb18ozm0/1/ - Current behavior I'm encountering (notice that only the cube position has been changed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OrbitControls` was not designed to support a camera that is a child of a rotated or translated parent.

Previously, your code worked because `camera.lookAt()` ignored the parent's transform; now `camera.lookAt()` honors the transform.

The change in behavior you are seeing is due to [this PR](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/14517).

three.js r.99

Comment: I understand. So basically what I did so far was not the standard way to do it. What would be the correct way to handle this instead?

Comment: If you still need help, please post a new question with your updated code.

Comment: My bad that I didn't noticed the PR which actually updated this and I wasn't prepared for it.

I simply handled it by using the OrbitControls target and moved the camera away from the mesh itself. I modified the OrbitControls source to follow the target instead of pointing at it from the same position and now everything works as it did before !